# Delete duplication of table item's

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have to delete duplication from my table where item's duplicate for user
Example table

```
Id   |  User  | item | count 
1    |   max  | coco |  2
2    |   max  | nut  |  4
3    |   max  | image|  1
4    |   max  | coco |  4
```

How to create sql query to delete all duplicate where, have a lot of user's.

I try to find this duplicate by :

```
SELECT id, user, item, COUNT(id) AS licznik
FROM Users
GROUP BY user, item
HAVING licznik > 1;
```

Comment: Why are the ids not unique?  I would expect `id` to be unique.

Comment: The rows are all different from each other. Which of the rows do you consider duplicates? Which of the rows do you want to keep, which do you want to delete? Please tell us the rule you want to apply here.

Comment: The id is unique but i write wrong number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care which row remains, you can use a query such as the following to keep the row with the minimum id:

```
delete u
    from users u
         (select user, item, min(id) as min_id
          from users u
          group by user, item
          having count(*) > 1
         ) ui
         using (user, item)
    where u.id > min_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using common expression table to receive data with row number over specified columns (window function). And then delete with row number larger than 1. I don't have mysql database to check if it works but on Microsoft sql server below query works like a charm. I read documentation of mysql and this should also work.

```
;with cte as (
select 
row_number() over (partition by [User], item order by Id) as rn
from Users
)
delete c from cte c where rn > 1
```

Comment: I try the both and doesn't work. Bof i use old version of mysql like MarinaDB. I am going to find another way to do it.